# Iphone: Autoscroll on selected indexPath in table

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I`m working with a tableview controller where new rows are added manually by the user on a secondary controller and then returning to the tableview with the new row highlighted.

I am using the following to highlight the row:

```
[self.shoppingCartTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath
  animated:YES 
  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
```

The highlighting works, but it does not automatically scroll to the row. Am I doing something wrong, or is there another way to make it work as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works perfectly for me.  I tried it in a test application and posted the code here: [Sample App](http://lingsdesigns.com/public/TestNav.zip)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your effort, especially with your sample app!

Guess it is something else thats wrong with my code then.. back to debugging ;)